# How to execute bolt commands other than in powershell?

Tags: powershell, puppet, puppet-bolt

I know we can write `bolt` commands as below in `powershell` and save it as .ps1

```
bolt task run package action=install name=apache2
```

We can excute that `powershell` script to run `bolt` commands.

But are there any other different methods to execute `bolt` commands other than `powershell`.

kindly let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Bolt is a command-line tool, so you can use any compatible command-line shell to execute Bolt commands.

You mention saving Bolt commands in a powershell script and executing them from there. I think Bolt plans might be useful to you. Check out the Bolt [Getting started guide](https://puppet.com/docs/bolt/latest/getting_started_with_bolt.html) - it details creating a plan that includes a Bolt task and a bash script.